Snort3 в WSL2 для защиты Windows
установил и настроил snort3 в Windows 10 WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.03). Может ли snort обрабатывать пакеты которые идут на Windows из сети и как это сделать т.е. защитить и Windows 10? WSL Mirror Mode не помогает, ip windows добавлен в snort.lua (HOME_NET). Любая информация по данному вопросу приветствуется, настройка выполнена в соответствии с  https://www.zenarmor.com/docs/linux-tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-snort-on-ubuntu-linux.
